# SSL Error coneecting from Sprint Client code to Websphere MQ server

Tags: ssl, ibm-mq

We are using below setup

1) Java code using client mode connection to Websphere MQ

```
<bean id="murexJmsConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
        <property name="hostName" value="${mx.mq.hostName}" />
        <property name="port" value="${mx.mq.port}" />
        <property name="queueManager" value="${mx.mq.queueManager}" />
        <property name="channel" value="${mx.mq.channel}" />
        <property name="SSLCipherSuite" value="${mx.mq.cipher.suite}"/>
        <property name="transportType">
            <util:constant static-field="com.ibm.mq.jms.JMSC.MQJMS_TP_CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

2) Open JDK 1.7 is installed in Linux Server

3) Websphere MQ Version - MQ 7.0.1.13

4) We have configured SSL certificates for connection.

**We are getting below exception**

```
retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'Q3TEST' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'myhost'.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2397' ('MQRC_JSSE_ERROR').
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'Q3TEST' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'myhost'. Check the queue manager is started and if running in client mode, check there is a listener running. Please see the linked exception for more information.
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:608)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:236)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:421)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6807)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6204)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:278)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createCommonConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6155)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:115)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:198)
        at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:184)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.createSharedConnection(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:403)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.refreshSharedConnection(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:388)
        at com.abnamro.nl.marrs.utilities.spring.jms.OmDefaultMessageListenerContainer.refreshConnectionUntilSuccessful(OmDefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1046)
        at com.abnamro.nl.marrs.utilities.spring.jms.OmDefaultMessageListenerContainer.recoverAfterListenerSetupFailure(OmDefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1026)
        at com.abnamro.nl.marrs.utilities.spring.jms.OmDefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(OmDefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1193)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2397' ('MQRC_JSSE_ERROR').
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:223)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2397;AMQ9204: Connection to host 'myhost(1414)' rejected. [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2397;AMQ9771: SSL handshake failed. [1=javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException[No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)],3=myhost/1.1.1.1:1414 (myhost),4=SSLSocket.startHandshake,5=default]],3=myhost(1414),5=RemoteTCPConnection.protocolConnect]
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1809)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:336)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2397;AMQ9771: SSL handshake failed. [1=javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException[No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)],3=myhost/1.1.1.1:1414 (myhost),4=SSLSocket.startHandshake,5=default]
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteTCPConnection.protocolConnect(RemoteTCPConnection.java:950)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.system.RemoteConnection.connect(RemoteConnection.java:1075)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.system.RemoteConnectionPool.getConnection(RemoteConnectionPool.java:338)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1488)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.activate(Handshaker.java:470)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.kickstartHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1438)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1308)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteTCPConnection.protocolConnect(RemoteTCPConnection.java:944)
        ... 17 more
```

Comment: It looks like your client and server can't agree on a protocol.  I don't know anything about Websphere specifically, but when I see `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)` I wonder - does your server only support TLS (after all, these days it really should be)?  Can you make your client use TLS instead of SSL?

Comment: You should check the value of ${mx.mq.cipher.suite} and the cipher suite configured on the server connection channel (${mx.mq.channel}) on your queue manager. These should match.

Comment: cipher suite used by client and cipher specs configured at MQ server are correct

Comment: @LDMJoe - We are using TLS protocol, so we don't suspect protocol is the issue

Answer (score 0):

We are able to solve this issue.

**Earlier we were using below client library versions**

Removed the following MQ related jars (and their dependencies) from our application:

```
1) jmqi-7.0.jar

2) mq-7.0.jar

3) mqjms-7.0.jar

4) commonservices-7.0.jar

5) headers-7.0.jar
```

**Which we changed to**

Downloaded this MQ client distribution from IBM site: mqc8_8.0.0.4_linuxx86-64.tar.gz

```
Added 2 jars from this distribution:

1) com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar

2) jms.jar



Added their dependency as follows:

<dependency>

  <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>

  <artifactId>allclient</artifactId>

  <version>8.0.0.4</version>

</dependency>



<dependency>

  <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>

  <artifactId>jms</artifactId>

  <version>8.0.0.4</version>

</dependency>
```